# Changing lineWidth for 1 side of a canvas polygon?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have been using code based on the code in this JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/qQA88/) to create a hexagonal grid.  I'm trying to figure out how to outline groups of hexagons in a thicker line, to indicate a "territory" of sorts.  HexagonGrid.prototype.drawHex() is the code that draws each hexagon, side-by-side... specifically with:

```
this.context.beginPath();
this.context.moveTo(x0 + this.width - this.side, y0);
this.context.lineTo(x0 + this.side, y0);
this.context.lineTo(x0 + this.width, y0 + (this.height / 2));
this.context.lineTo(x0 + this.side, y0 + this.height);
this.context.lineTo(x0 + this.width - this.side, y0 + this.height);
this.context.lineTo(x0, y0 + (this.height / 2));
this.context.closePath();
this.context.stroke();
```

Now, I know that each of those lineTo calls represents one side of the hexagon. If I kept a JSON object representing each hexagon, I could keep track of which side of a hexagon would have to be a thicker lineWidth, in order to create an enclosed territory.

Example:

```
var hex = { n: null,
s: null, 
nw: null,
ne: null, 
sw: null,
se: true }
```

In that case, the Southeastern side could be a thicker lineWidth.

I understand that you cannot change the lineWidth inside of a single stroke() call. I've seen examples of people breaking the path for every side of a polygon to create this effect, but then I wouldn't be able to fill these hexagons with color, because of the broken path.

Given a giant JSON array of hexagons as listed above, with properties for each side, can I achieve the effect I'm looking for? I'm thinking that as a last resort I'd have to draw the grid as usual, then draw the thicker outlines on top, but even then I'm not entirely sure how I'd loop through my JSON array to correctly get all the lineTo() functions to create a proper "territory".

Any thoughts would be helpful.

Edit: I'm an idiot (like lots of other SO questions, eh?).  I could just let the hexagon get draw as shown above in one stroke(), then while the coordinates are still in memory, draw the thicker sides on top.  I'll report back with an answer.

Comment: The method you describe in your edit should work fine, but don't beat yourself up over having an "ahaaa" moment ;-)

Comment: Well, I try not to come to SO unless I've thought about it overnight, and possibly ran it by a friend. I also know how frustrating it can be to have a poorly worded question... so I try hard to write it all down.  Getting an "a-ha!" moment was a good ending at least.  

Though, I will say... the method I described isn't quite as good as I expected. Because they are all line segments and not all 1 line, they don't smoothly fit together and are a bit disjointed (and even look like different lineWidths).  I'll have to manually created a continuous line to make this work.

Comment: About "filling" your resulting hexagon: (1) beginPath & draw the full thinner hexagon (2) stroke & fill the thinner full hexagon. (3) beginPath & stroke the couple thicker lines. You might use `context.lineCap="round"` to ease the transition between thin and thicker lines--sometimes that improves the fit between thin & thick. Cheers!

Comment: I couldn't resist trying it: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/945Jv/

Comment: Wow, you wrote your own functions for the hexagons too! Ha!  You were right about the lineCap, I wasn't aware of that property.  It helped make the disjointed lines seem more smooth... I'm definitely happy with the results.